# Qualitative properties of solutions to a ordinary differential equation.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this problem : $$\begin{cases} -(p(t)u'(t))'=f(t,u(t))\\u(0)=u(+\infty)=0\end{cases}$$

we have that $u$ is continues,  $f:\mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty} u(t)=0.$

How to prove that : $u$ is differentiable, $pu'$ is continuous and $\sup_{t\geq0} |p(t)u'(t)|<\infty$ where $p>0$ and $\frac1p\in L^1(0,+\infty)$ ??

Thank you.

Comment: Is $p(t)$ just an arbitrary function? Or do we know that it is continuous?

Comment: no just that 1/p\in L^1

Comment: @msteve have you an idea for $\sup_{t\geq0}|p(t)u'(t)|<\infty$ ?

Comment: Did you miss an assumption such as $p\in L^{1}$?

Comment: no $\frac{1}{p}\in L^1$

Comment: You're not assuming $p$ is locally integrable?

Comment: no p is not locally integrable

Comment: @Vrouvrou : If you want someone to know that you've left a message, then use the '@' ping. I took a second look at this problem and just caught your last comment.

Comment: @T.A.E. is a solution of the problem $\begin{cases} -(p(t)u'(t))'=f(t,u(t))\\u(0)=u(+\infty)=0\end{cases}$ is bounded ?